# JQuery content dissapearing in IE8

Tags: jquery, html

I have an issue with JQuery in IE7/IE8. My Code below is in the top of my page which gets inserted into a CMS page. This then loads the content (FAQ navigation) into an empty div in the main page.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/wcsstore/MadisonsStorefrontAssetStore/images/js/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$.get('/wcsstore/MadisonsStorefrontAssetStore/images/contentspots/viva/faqnavigation.html', function(data) {
 $('#faq_links').html(data);
});
</script>
```

As you can see from the above the content then gets inserted into the empty div in my page, which is the first  in the page.

```
<div id="faq_links"></div>
```

I have tested this in FF, Opera, Safari, Chrome and IE9, all are fine, the issue comes with IE7 + IE8. Sometimes the navigation will load (But selecting a link will make it dissapear again) other times it just leaves a blank space where it should be. The file it links to is just a simple ul with about 20 links.

I have tried adding an alert into the page to see if it's not loading the JQuery by adding

```
alert('Load was performed.');
```

just before the }); which worked, and gave the "Loaded" popup everytime the page was loaded but still didn't load the content.

I can't link you to the page because it is in a development CMS. Any help in finding out why it makes my navigation vanish would be appricated.

I'm happy to answer any question you may have or provide more info if required.

Thanks. Matt.

Comment: Try to give a feedback ... to know the solution of the issue,does it work or not?

Comment: The code works in all browsers other than IE7 + IE8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try adding `$(document).ready`:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
   $.get('/wcsstore/MadisonsStorefrontAssetStore/images/contentspots/viva/faqnavigation.html',   function(data) {
    $('#faq_links').html(data);
   });
})
</script>
```

Comment: This worked thanks very much for pointing out where I had made the mistake. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try add random number to the request ....
I don't know will it solve the problem or not ... i hope so

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.get('/wcsstore/MadisonsStorefrontAssetStore/images/contentspots/viva/faqnavigation.html', { rnd: Math.floor(Math.random()*11) }, function(data) {
    $('#faq_links').html(data);
     });
  });
```